# Split and sum in some cases

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I need you infinite knowledge. I have some kind of data in a column (text)

| state |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0,0 |
| 13 |
| 13,27,0 |
| 0,0,0 |

Is a text column, but it can have a number, or many numbers separate by commas (not defined how long). The number 0 means OK and any other number is a code error. When it has more than one number is part of the business (patrons).

Anyway, i need to know if any file is OK (0) or it has some error (one number different of 0). I thought if i can do a split i could converter it to number and sum, if sum is 0, means all are 0. If it sum different so it is error code. But i have problem doing the split, i try with split_part but i must choose the position and string_to_array too i have problem. It table has other column but this is the key for the problem.

`SELECT split_part(state, ',', position)`

So in this example (the table is just the example and not the result of sql in that way. Just the i need to know):

| state | result | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | OK | 0 (0) |
| 0,0 | OK | 0 (0+0) |
| 13 | NOK | 13 (13) |
| 13,27,0 | NOK | 40 (13+27+0) |
| 0,0,0 | OK | 0 (0+0+0) |

1.- Like i said, i need to know if is 0 ok or not, because i must work with other columna of the "zero" result.

2.- Sum is only an idea, maybe could be other way.

Please help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyway, i need to know if any file is OK (0) or it has some error (one number different of 0).

It's text data, so you could just use a simple regular expression query.  The following query would list ONLY states that contain at least one error.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE state ~ '[1-9]';
```

Using the same technique, if you want to see all of the data, but with a boolean showing ok or not ok, then your query could look like this:

```
SELECT id, state, not state ~ '[1-9]' as ok FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly and was very short.

Answer (score 1):

A normalized table without delimiter, would save the unnest, which costs time

```
CREATE TABLE ExTable 
    (ID  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"state" varchar(7))
;
    
INSERT INTO ExTable 
    ("state")
VALUES
    ('0'),
    ('0,0'),
    ('13'),
    ('13,27,0'),
    ('0,0,0')
;
```

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT
ID,state,unnest(string_to_array(state, ','))::int val
FROM Extable)
SELECT state,CASE WHEN SUM(val) = 0 THEn 'OK' ELSE 'NOK' END result, SUM(val) sum
FROM CTE GROUP BY ID,state
ORDER By ID
```

| state | result | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | OK | 0 |
| 0,0 | OK | 0 |
| 13 | NOK | 13 |
| 13,27,0 | NOK | 40 |
| 0,0,0 | OK | 0 |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7RuNzUit)